# Unity - How to block a canvas when another canvas is on

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I have one canvas with game over and one canvas with pause menu with button on mainscreen. When i play and i died and my game over canvas appear but the button from pausemenu canvas it does not disappear or disable and can be pressed and pausemenu canvas appear over gameover. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50llW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is use the .SetActive() function on your button! When you are on the game over screen, only the elements from that canvas should be active.

To begin, you would declare the pause button a public GameObject in your script. Then in the start, you call the pause button when the game begins, however, if gameOver, set it to false.

```
public GameObject pauseButton;

void Start(){
pauseButton.SetActive(true);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
if(other.tag == "Enemy"){
pauseButton.SetActive(false);
gameOver();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need make system for game states like pause, ingame, menu, dead. And then have on canvas parent GameObjects for each screen (buttons and parts of each screen under this objects) and then just enable/disable this parent GameObjects.

so when you are dead it can look like this

```
void UpdateUI(){  
    if(status == status.dead)
        canv_pause.SetActive(false);
        canv_ingame.SetActive(false);
        canv_menu.SetActive(false);
        canv_dead.SetActive(true);
    if(status == status.menu)
        canv_pause.SetActive(false);
        canv_ingame.SetActive(false);
        canv_menu.SetActive(true);
        canv_dead.SetActive(false);
    //etc...
}
```